# C++ - Compare two .jpeg/.png pictures and print different pixels into matrix

Tags: c++, image, matrix

I am new to C++ and struggle a lot. I want to do simple program to compare two given .png /.jpeg pictures and print different pixels into matrix into console.

I want to use libpng or libjpeg library and stantard libraries.

**So for example:** Lets say picture1 contains only white pixels and has 5x5 pixels . And picture2 contains white pixels as background and big letter "T" in black pixels and has 5x5 pixels. So the result printed in console will be:

`- 0 1 2 3 4 
 0 X X X X X
 1 o o X o o
 2 o o X o o
 3 o o X o o
 4 o o X o o`

`X` - means pixels on this possition are different,
`o` - means pixels are the same on this possition

My first idea was loading both files into matrices and compare them something like `picture1Matrix[ i ][ j ] == picture2Matrix[ i ][ j ]`. Biggest problem for me is loading picture into matrix. So far i was able to open stream.

```
std::ifstream inputStreamFile1( fileName1, std::ios::binary );

if( !inputStreamFile1.is_open() || !inputStreamFile1.good() ) throw  "Couldn't open first given file!";
```

Also i dont know if opening it as binary file is proper way.

**Would you be so kind and help me with simple example how to this specific task? I am looking for code to load small given .png/.jpeg file into matrix so i can compare**

*This is my first question so i apologize for bad formating of question and also for my bad english.*

**EDIT: And also i dont know which format to choose. .jpeg or .png. I dont know the differences in working with pictures formats**

Comment: Honestly I'd propose to start with BMP then. Or, even better, with simple 2d arrays - this will allow you to get the logic right at some point, and then proceed to the actual image formats.

Comment: @iehrlich that might actually be good idea. My original goal of this little project was to take two random pictures and with listed libraries produce result which i chose to represent as matrix of differences.

Comment: This is the only right way at any level of expertise and problem complexity - the reasonable decomposition of your problem to the set of smaller problems that you might solve independently, and from which you might construct the actual "big" solution :)

Comment: @iehrlich yea :) my first tought was to take more common formats of pictures and work with them. But without any doubt the .bmp or .raw format will do the same. Should i edit my original post or something?

Comment: well, actually, I think it's worth giving it a try in the first place, and then asking for some help when any particular issues are encountered. As long as you're not developing a full-on production solution (load is low, no hard stability requirements) you might just gather this code (or, merely, understanding of the code) piece by piece from tutorials, examples etc. - combining them together you'll eventually get something resembling a real application - probably with our help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that they have the same dimensions, you can use Intel's OpenCV library to do these operations.

Given that you have the library installed, you can then do this operation pretty painlessly:

```
//read in the images
cv::Mat picture1= imread("image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
cv::Mat picture2= imread("image2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
cv::Mat difference;

//compute the difference
cv::absdiff(picture1, picture2, difference);
```

The `difference` now contains the pixels that are not the same. To view it, use `imshow("windowname", difference)` and to print it to the terminal stream do

`cout << "Difference = "<< endl << " "  << Difference << endl << endl;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer buy as I said in my original post i want to use only **standart libraries and libpng/libjpeg**. As far as I know OpenCV is neither of them.